# n-sphere stereographic projection in hyperspherical coords

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, stereographic-projections

I need atlases for working with $n$-spheres, specifically $S^1$, $S^3$, and $S^5$.  Stereographic projection charts seem like the most straightforward and economical way to make these. However, I want to work only in terms of hyper-spherical coordinates on the spheres, rather than the usual Cartesian coordinates in the $n+1$ space, since I need to be free of any reference to that higher dimensional embedding space.

Not finding such equations anywhere I attempted to derive these charts. I take the n-spheres as centered at the origin of the hyper-spherical coordinates, and project from the "north" and "south" poles onto the equatorial hyper-plane.  I define the generalized azimuthal angles over the domain $[\pi/2, -\pi/2]$ rather than the more common convention of $[0, \pi]$.  Then substituting the correct coordinate transformation equations from $n+1$ Cartesian to hyper-spherical coordinates into the Cartesian stereographic projection equations and calculating the radius coordinate in the projection hyperplane one gets, for any $n > 1$,

$r_1 = \frac{\cos t}{1-\sin t}$ "north" pole projection,  $t \in (\pi/2, -\pi/2]$

$r_2 = \frac{\cos t}{1+\sin t}$ "south pole" $t\in [\pi/2, -\pi/2)$

where $t$ = the highest (or last) generalized azimuthal angle added for that dimension.  All the remaining $n-1$ angle coordinates of that hyper-spherical coordinate set carry over to the projection hyperplane unchanged, for both charts, resulting in the requisite number of n coordinates for the n-dimensional hyperplane.

$n = 1$ is a slightly special case since there is only one angle on the 1-sphere, the "latitude", so the domain of $t$ is $[0, 2\pi)$ in this case, with the same equations for $r_1$ and $r_2$ mapping a point on the circle to a point on the real line thru the circle's "equator".  This completes the three atlases needed.

However, I have not derived these results completely rigorously, but had to rely on intuition and inference at some steps in the higher dimensions, so have some reservations about their general validity. If anyone has or knows of a correct derivation of atlases meeting these requirements I would greatly appreciate seeing it or a reference to it.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please edit and use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to properly format math expressions.

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but I don't understand how spherical coordinates are going to help avoid reference to ambient Cartesian coordinates in $\mathbf{R}^{n+1}$ if ordinary stereographic coordinates (i.e., Cartesian coordinates on $\mathbf{R}^{n}$ for the $n$-sphere) fail to do so.

Comment: The stereographic projection chart can be expressed entirely in terms of the n angle coordinates that lie entirely on the unit n-sphere, without any reference to the n+1th coordinate, the radius, of the n+1 spherical coordinates of the embedding space.    The dimensionality of the chart matches that of the sphere, which is what's wanted.  Using the Cartesian stereo projection requires all n+1 Cartesian coordinates in the chart equations, so the chart has one more variable than the dimensionality of the manifold of interest, the unit n-sphere.

Comment: It's implied that these are *unit* n-spheres, but it's not stated explicitly in the original post.  Perhaps that helps.

Comment: What I meant by "stereographic coordinates" may be what you mean by the inverse map, i.e., the parametrization of $S^n$ minus a point by $\mathbf{R}^{n}$,$$\mathbf{x} \mapsto \frac{(\mathbf{x}, \|\mathbf{x}\|^{2}-1)}{\|\mathbf{x}\|^{2}+1}.$$These depend on $n$ coordinates, not $n+1$. The inverse map does naturally use all the coordinates on the ambient space.

Comment: Thanks, yes, understood.  It's the presence of that n+1th Cartesian coordinate of the ambient space in the inverse map that becomes a problem in this physics work.  The unit spheres in question have a well-defined physical meaning beyond the geometric one, thus the n angles on them do too, and I can work with those.  There is no physical meaning (as yet) for the ambient spaces into which the spheres are embedded, so there is no way so far to work with (give a physical meaning to) that n+1th coordinate in the Cartesian case.